# Place a parameter label under each drawing using Table

Tags: plotting, graphics, list-manipulation, labeling

I use this code to draw the function by `ContourPlot3D`Multiple times

```
 {ContourPlot3D[
  x z + y z - x y z == 0, {x, 0, 2}, {y, 0, 2}, {z, 0, 2}], 
 ContourPlot3D[
  x z + y z - x y z == 0.2, {x, 0, 2}, {y, 0, 2}, {z, 0, 2}], 
 ContourPlot3D[
  x z + y z - x y z == 0.4, {x, 0, 2}, {y, 0, 2}, {z, 0, 2}]}
```

My question is how can I type the function value under each drawing[image]

Is there a better way to draw the function in a table shape and to take selected values with the values printed under each drawing c= .

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Labeled`.

```
f = Function[{x, y, z}, x z + y z - x y z]
tmp = StringTemplate["C=``"]
plots = Labeled[
     ContourPlot3D[f[x, y, z] == #, {x, 0, 2}, {y, 0, 2}, {z, 0, 2}],
     tmp[#]] & /@ {0.0, 0.2, 0.4};
Grid[{plots}]
```

[image: three plot]

Answer (score 9):

The functionality you are looking for is `Epilog`,

```
c1 = ContourPlot3D[
   x z + y z - x y z == 0, {x, 0, 2}, {y, 0, 2}, {z, 0, 2}, 
   Epilog -> {Text[Style["c=0", 22], Scaled[{0.1, 0.0}]]}];

c2 = ContourPlot3D[
   x z + y z - x y z == 0.2, {x, 0, 2}, {y, 0, 2}, {z, 0, 2}, 
   Epilog -> {Text[Style["c=0.2", 22], Scaled[{0.1, 0.0}]]}];

c3 = ContourPlot3D[
   x z + y z - x y z == 0.4, {x, 0, 2}, {y, 0, 2}, {z, 0, 2}, 
   Epilog -> {Text[Style["c=0.4", 22], Scaled[{0.1, 0.0}]]}];

Grid[{{c1, c2, c3}}]
```

[image]

Comment: Possibly, also a `Grid` with the graphs on one raw and the text on another ?